# How would I use setState for this particular example?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, debugging

I'm getting warnings in the console that says:

```
Do not mutate state directly. Use setState()  react/no-direct-mutation-state
```

For `this.state.turn = this.state.turn === 'X' ? 'O' : 'X';` I changed it to `this.setState({turn: 'X' ? 'O' : 'X'});` which does get rid of the warning but my in doing so, my program doesn't execute the way it should which leads me to believe I'm doing it wrong.

For `this.state.totalMoves++;` I changed it to `this.setState({totalMoves: this.state.totalMoves++});` but I still get that warning.

What's the correct way of achieving this?

Here's my code:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        turn: 'X',
        board: Array(9).fill(''),
        totalMoves: 0
    }
}

if(this.state.board[box.dataset.square] === '') {
    // was previously this.state.board[box.dataset.square] = this.state.turn

    this.setState({turn: this.state.board[box.dataset.square]});
    box.innerText = this.state.turn;

    this.state.turn = this.state.turn === 'X' ? 'O' : 'X';
    this.state.totalMoves++;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Firstly` setState is asynchronous and hence the update of setState is not reflected immediately, you can make use of setState callback to execute something after state is updated

```
this.setState(state => {
   box.innerText = state.turn;
   return { turn: state.board[box.dataset.square]}
});
```

`Secondly`, setState provides a functional callback method to update state based on previous state

In your case you would write it like

```
this.setState(prevState => ({
     turn: prevState.turn === 'X' ? 'O' : 'X', 
     totalMoves: prevState.totalMoves + 1
});
```